# Sails js send 404 status for missing static files

Tags: express, sails.js

I have my sails app set to serve static files from a custom directory

```html
module.exports.http = {
    customMiddleware: function(app) {
        app.use('/', express.static(process.cwd() + '/public'));
    },
    middleware: {
        xframe: require('lusca').xframe('SAMEORIGIN'),
        order: [
            'xframe',
            'startRequestTimer',
            'cookieParser',
      'customMiddleware',
            'session',
            'myRequestLogger',
            'bodyParser',
            'handleBodyParserError',
            'compress',
            'methodOverride',
            'poweredBy',
            '$custom',
            'router',
            'www',
            'favicon',
            '404',
            '500'
        ]
    }
};
```

and my frontend app get served using the route

```html
    '/*': {
        view: 'index',
        skipAssets: true,
        skipRegex: /(^\/api\/.*$)|^\/csrfToken$/
    }
```

but I've noticed that if I request a file that doesn't exist i.e /css/whataloadofrubbish.css it just hangs when it should send a 404. Not sure what I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

Ah compared to another app and found my notFound.js find was wrong